Can I get an EASA Class 1 Medical with a cured depression?
I had depressions and from January this year to last week I took escitalopram 10mg daily.
I want to be a pilot and apply to the european flight academy at the end of 2025.
Is this a problem to get my medical?
Of course I cant hide my past but because there’s around half a year between the meds and the medical test is it realistic that I get a medical?
Thanks in advance!

This is similar to a question about PTSD.

Different question, same answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84891/7532
